# Select2 - render search input instead of clickable select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Using [select2](https://select2.org/), is it possible to render the search input instead of clickable select with search input in the dropdown, so the user can focus it immediately with either clicking it or going down the form 
with a <kbd>TAB</kbd> key?

Default:

[image]

What I (roughly) need:

[image]

My guess: it is more friendly to end-user, as it saves him/her a click.

Reading the docs and googling I did not find any out of the box solution and before implementing one myself I just want to make sure there isn't any.

Comment: For multiple select (with attr [multiple](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes) or option [tokenSeparators](https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags)) there's no extra input in dropdown

Comment: that's clever, will see what I can do with it

Comment: @wscourge You are talking about [link](https://select2.org/appearance) as expected output?

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya I am not sure what behind the link you mean exactly

Comment: @wscourge It provide same funtionality as you mentioned http://prntscr.com/m2j3gs

Comment: ah ok, yeah, same as barbsan mentioned before; I'm looking into it